# Find multiple distinct values replace adjacent cells if true find next if false

Tags: excel, vba

I have found a lot on this topic and am new to VBA so I am trying to locate specific text (Up to 10) in column A and if found replace adjacent column B with the text in "".  I don't know how to get this to continue to loop until its done. Getting a compile error End IF without Block If and its not doing anything.

Example

```
Sub Check()
    Dim ColRange As Range
    Dim cl As Range
    Set ColRange = Range("A1:A500")
    For Each cl In ColRange.Cells

        If cell.Value = "AEO" Then cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "02553E106"
    Next
        If cell.Value = "IMAX" Then cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "45245E109"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: LIke I said I am new to VBA

Comment: Is this what it should be then?                                                             If cell.Value = "AEO" Then cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "02553E106"
Else
If cell.Value = "IMAX" Then cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "45245E109"
End If

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect.

```
If *conditions here* Then

  // Put stuff here

Else

  // More stuff here

End If
```

Every if block needs its own `End If`